# Node.js error: write after end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a basic web server with node.js and a root-directory where several `.html` files are stored. So what I'am doing is

```
var path = request.url;
getHtmlFile = function(req,res){
  fs.readFile('html'+path,funtion(err,data){
       if(err){ 
          console.log("no file"); 
       }
       else { 
          res.write(data);
          res.end();
          console.log("file found");
       }
  });
}
```

This code gives me following error :

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:428:15)
    at mypath\server.js:43:18
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

I'am not very familiar with node.js, so it would be nice, if someone can explain me, what I am missing.

Comment: You forgot the closing`}` for your `else` :)

Comment: That was my error, i will edit this

Comment: Are you sure the "res" hasn't been closed before calling the function?
I mean, it seems that ptoblem is in other code, not in the posted excerpt.
Anyway the fs.readFile function is async so the "res" could be closed somewhen before callback.

Comment: @greedsin so what was exactly your solution? I'm facing similar issues with `mysql.query()` inside a `fs.readFile()`